# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 in Sectioned RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to get current position of object in RecyclerView in method `onClick()`. Here is one fragment of code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnAccept) {
            int position              = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Notification notification = mNotifications.get(position); // Here is an error
            mFragmentPageOne.acceptMembership(notification.getGroupId());
        } else if (v == btnDecline) {

        }
    }

@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, Notification item, @ViewType int viewType) {
    NotificationHolder notificationHolder = (NotificationHolder) holder;
    final int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

    notificationHolder.tvNotification.setText(
              item.getNotification() + " ti je poslao zahtev za clanstvo u ekipu "
            + item.getGroupName());
    long timestamp = DateUtil.getDifference(item.getTimestamp());
    // Converting timestamp into x ago format
    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(timestamp)),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    notificationHolder.tvTimestamp.setText(timeAgo);

    notificationHolder.btnAccept.setTag(position);
    notificationHolder.btnDecline.setTag(position);

    setAnimation(notificationHolder.mRelativeLayout, position);
}
```

So i'm trying to find a position of current selected object in list. This list also has some sectioned items. 
Here i'm setting data to the array of objects:

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    boolean error = obj.getBoolean("error");
    JSONArray ary = obj.getJSONArray("membership");
    if (!error) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject innerObj = ary.getJSONObject(i);
            Notification notification = new Notification();
            notification.setNotification(innerObj.getString("name"));
            notification.setTimestamp(innerObj.getString("createdAt"));
            notification.setGroupId(innerObj.getInt("group_id"));
            notification.setGroupName(innerObj.getString("group_name"));
            notification.setCategory("Membership Requests");
            mNotificationList.add(notification);
        }

        mAdapter = new NotificationHeaderListAdapter(getActivity(), mNotificationList, FragmentPageOne.this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The whole error log:

```
Process: com.solaris.timster, PID: 4850
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
  at com.solaris.timster.adapter.NotificationHeaderListAdapter$NotificationHolder.onClick(NotificationHeaderListAdapter.java:99)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Arraylists in Java are Zero based. Try `Notification notification = mNotifications.get(Position-1);`

Comment: @Jens post this comment as answer, because it solved my problem and probably it will help others as well.

Comment: I have done. Please upvote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arraylists in Java are Zero based. Try `Notification notification = mNotifications.get(Position-1);`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
notificationHolder.checkParentView.setTag(itemsData.ge(position));
notificationHOlder.checkParentView.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);
private View.OnClickListener checkedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int positon = (Integer) v.getTag();
    }
};
```